# Read lines batch wise in c#

Tags: c#

I have below code which is reading a .json stream line by line. since it will be a lengthy process, I have decided that I will take 100 lines at a time before I call my main function. and so the below code works fine. but this also gives me an issue if number of lines is less than 100, in that case my main function will not be called. how can I optimize my below code to handle both the scenario i.e. read maximum 100 lines at a time and pass it to main function or read all the lines if it is below 100

```cs
public async void ReadJsonStream()
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (Stream data = await manager.DownloadBlob(null, "TestMultipleLines.json", null))
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(data, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            int counter = 1;
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            
            while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                lines.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());

                if (counter == 100)
                {
                    counter = 1;
                    // call main function with line
                    lines.Clear();
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need some code after your `while` loop which checks to see whether `lines` is empty, and calls the main function if not

Comment: Your main function will not be called even in case your file contains 110 row for the last 10 rows. You need to call the function at loop exit if the lines list is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel what you are trying to do is wrong. How will you parse 100 lines? Do you want to rebuild from scratch a Json deserializer? And what will happen if some piece of json is split between the line 100 and the line 101?

But in the end, you asked for something and I'll give you what you asked.

```
public async void ReadJsonStream()
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (Stream data = await manager.DownloadBlob(null, "TestMultipleLines.json", null))
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(data, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            string line;

            while ((line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);

                if (lines.Count == 100)
                {
                    // call main function with lines
                    lines.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (lines.Count != 0)
            {
                // call main function with lines
                lines.Clear(); // useless
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As others noted, you forgot the "additional" call to `// call main function with lines` at the end of the cycle. I've even modified the code. You don't need to `.Peek()`, `.ReadLine()` returns `null` at the end of the input stream. You made your method `async`... You could make it fully async by using `.ReadLineAsync()`.

Note that the `JsonSerializer` of Json.NET already has a `Deserialize` method that accept a `TextReader` (and a `StreamReader` **is** a `TextReader`), and that method will read the file "a piece at a time", and won't preload it before parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a check after the while loop. If the lines list is not empty, call main.

```
public async void ReadJsonStream()
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (Stream data = await manager.DownloadBlob(null, "TestMultipleLines.json", null))
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(data, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            int counter = 1;
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                lines.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());

                if (counter == 100)
                {
                    counter = 1;
                    // call main function with line
                    lines.Clear();
                }
                counter++;
            }
            if (lines.Count > 0)
                // call main function with line
        }
    }


}
``
```